# Why is std::next_permutation skipping over some permutations?

Tags: c++, permutation

The expected output for "opt" (or any combination of these 3 letters) should be "opt", "top", and "pot" (in any order) but this program is only finding and matching "top" and "pot". next_permutation never seems to go over "opt", and I'm not sure what the problem is. The same problem arises when trying to find all permutations of "apt".

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

//int loadDictionary(istream& dictfile, vector<string>& dict);

int permute(string word, vector<string>& dict, vector<string>& results) {
std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());
while (next_permutation(word.begin(), word.end())){
    cout << "Permutation: " << word << endl;
    if (binary_search(dict.begin(), dict.end(), word)) {
        cout << "Match found: " << word << endl;
        results.push_back(word);
    }
}

    int matches = results.size();
    return matches;
}

int main() {
std::vector<string> dictionary;
std::vector<string> results;
std::string word;
ifstream fileName("words.txt");
cout << loadDictionary(fileName, dictionary);
cout << "\nEnter a string for a anagram: ";
    cin >> word;
    permute(word, dictionary, results);
cout << "\nMain complete\n";

}
```

Comment: `while (next_permutation(word.begin(), word.end()))` on line 12 will permute word *before* the loop enters the first time, which causes the first permutation to be missing. One way to fix this would be by changing your while-loop to a do-while loop, which would solve your problem by processing the initial word before actually permuting it.

Comment: See example at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: @Telescope thank you, changing it to a do while loop fixed it. Never though of using it since I figured it was redundant when a while loop usually does the job. I know this is out of the scope of the question, but do you know why binary search isn't matching some of the words? It works fine with a linear search but thats obviously much less efficient.

Comment: Binary search requires the container being searched to be sorted. My guess is it's not.

Comment: @JohnFilleau The text file contains 25,000 alphabetically sorted words so I don't think that is the case. I've double checked by using cout.

Comment: Copy the dictionary into a new container, sort it, and then compare it to the original. If they're equal, then it's not a sorting issue.

Comment: @NKI Can you post the code that actually fills `dictionary`? That could be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`std::next_permutation` does the permutation, so regular usage is with `do while`:

```
int permute(std::string word, std::vector<std::string>& dict, std::vector<std::string>& results) {
    std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());
    do {
        std::cout << "Permutation: " << word << std::endl;
        if (std::binary_search(dict.begin(), dict.end(), word)) {
            std::cout << "Match found: " << std::word << std::endl;
            results.push_back(word);
    } while (next_permutation(word.begin(), word.end()));
    int matches = results.size();
    return matches;
}
```

To check against dictionary, checking all permutations seems huge.

You might transform your dictionary into an 'anagram' dictionary.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<string>> make_anagram_dict(const std::vector<string>& words)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<string>> res;

    for (const auto& word : words) {
        auto anagram = word;
        std::sort(anagram.begin(), anagram.end());
        res[anagram].push_back(word);
    }
    return res;
}
```

then your main would be

```
int main() {
    std::vector<string> words;
    ifstream fileName("words.txt");
    loadDictionary(fileName, words);
    auto dict = make_anagram_dict(words);
    do {
       std::cout << "\nEnter a string for a anagram: ";
       std::string anagram;
       std::cin >> anagram;
       std::sort(anagram.begin(), anagram.end());
       auto it = dict.find(anagram);
       if (it != dict.end()) {
           for (const auto& word : it->second) {
               std::cout << "Match found: " << word << std::endl;
           }
       }
    } while (std::cin); // or other conditions to break the loop
    std::cout << "\nMain complete\n";
}
```